# Can't add Response Header with Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, response-headers

I have a Chrome extension, and I'm trying to get it to add a Response Header to all pages.

Here's what I have in the manifest:

```
"permissions": [
  "storage",
  "clipboardRead",
  "clipboardWrite",
  "webRequest",
  "webRequestBlocking",
  "background"
],
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background-script.js"]
},
```

Here's what I have in my background-script.js

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details){
    console.log('headers received');
    details.responseHeaders.push({ name: 'X-XSS-Protection', value: '0' });
    return { responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders };
}, {
    urls: ['<all_urls>'],
    types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "stylesheet", "script", "image", "object", "xmlhttprequest", "other"]
}, ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']);
```

I know that the background script executes, from putting a console.log in that file but outside the event listener, and observing it from the "Inspect views: background page" in the Extensions window.

However, I don't think the eventListener executes- I haven't seen that "headers received" message anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared a truckload of unnecessary permissions in your manifest file, but not the most important ones: Host permissions. For example, if you want to intercept every http(s) request, add the `"*://*/*"` [match pattern](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) to the permissions section of your `manifest.json`:

```
"permissions": [
  "webRequest",
  "webRequestBlocking",
  "*://*/*"
],
```